# Altering the state/position of a search form in a nav bar

Tags: javascript, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am trying to reposition a search form/button inside of my navbar with lingering problems.  My CSS has changed many times, and I have gotten the form and button to move, but into weir alignment that either changes the nav bar or the search form.  Here is my current CSS, which shows no changes from the default bootstrap state.  I want to make the search form a little longer, and have the bar and form move slightly down and to the left, in position with the nav list:

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Imported documents -->


<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/styles.css">


<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>TesterPage.</title>

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed menuIcon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- Brand Logo -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img alt="Brand" src="assets/logo.gif" class="img-responsive" id="brandImage" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search Bar</label>
            <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background:#30302f;
}

.container a{
  color: #fff;

}

.container a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #fff;
}


.menuIcon {
    background:rgb(200,200,200);
}

.navbar-brand {
    height:auto;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #30302f;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  top: 16px;
  left: -50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-form .navbar-right .form-class{
    left: -30px;
    top: 100px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;

}

#brandImage {
    max-width:60%;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {

    .navbar-brand {
    width:95%;
    padding:8px 2.5%;
    }

    #brandImage {
    max-width:100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width:990px) and (max-width:1200px) {
    .navbar-brand {
    width:250px;
    }
}
```

Many thanks!

EDIT:  I still try and edit the CSS code, and it slides my nav header to the left on the index, and misaligns it in other working pages  :/